# Javascript : testing two asynch calls before going to third function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

So I have two asynch calls going out to a webservice... both of them are needed for my third method.

How would you guys suggest doing this?

I tried setting a flag in one of my methods (the other method calls the third method and send in some data) ... so in my third method I tried this:

```
 thirdMethod: function (returnedData) {

        if (this.secondFunctionReturned != true) {
            setTimeout(this.thirdMethod, returnedData, 100);
        }
        else {}
```

But this timeout did not work (it didnt pass the data for me) -- just wondering what you guys think ... and thanks.

Comment: non-related style note: you don't need to compare a boolean to another boolean in an `if` statement.  just use `if(!this.secondFunctionReturned) { ...`, it's easier to read.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Presumably you're getting data back from each of the async calls and that's why you need them before firing your third. I'd have each of the async callbacks check to see if all required data is present and, if so, fire off your third function. Or you could use a counter, but again, presumably you have data already and the counter would just be unnecessarily additional.

Pseudo:

```
var dataFromCall1, dataFromCall2;

startAsync(function(data) {
    dataFromCall1 = data;
    if (dataFromCall2) {
        thirdFunction(dataFromCall1, dataFromCall2);
    }
});

startOtherAsync(function(data) {
    dataFromCall2 = data;
    if (dataFromCall1) {
        thirdFunction(dataFromCall1, dataFromCall2);
    }
});
```

Or less coupled:

```
var dataFromCall1, dataFromCall2;

startAsync(function(data) {
    dataFromCall1 = data;
    nextStep();
});

startOtherAsync(function(data) {
    dataFromCall2 = data;
    nextStep();
});

function nextStep() {
    if (dataFromCall1 && dataFromCall2) {
        thirdFunction(dataFromCall1, dataFromCall2);
    }
}
```

Or the counter:

```
var counter = 0;

startAsync(function() {
    // ...presumably some processing here...

    // Possibly fire next step
    handleCompletion();
});

startOtherAsync(function() {
    // ...presumably some processing here...

    // Possibly fire next step
    handleCompletion();
});

function handleCompletion() {
    if (++counter === 2) {
        thirdFunction();
    }
}
```

---

**Update**:

Regarding the question in the comments below:

> I tried this once then thought about the one instance that both of these return at the same time... couldn't there be a situation where this would fail if they both returned at the exact same time?

Good question, I should have addressed that originally: No, there is no possibility of both calls occurring simultaneously. JavaScript in web browsers is single-threaded (barring the explicit use of [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/), and even then interactions between the threads are explicit). If the callback for the first call is in progress when the second call completes, the second callback will be queued and only run when the first callback returns.

Comment: I tried this once then thought about the one instance that both of these return at the same time... couldn't there be a situation where this would fail if they both returned at the exact same time?

Comment: I like the counter method, because it will work regardless of whether there are 2 prerequisite calls or 20.

Comment: Ya, all of those look great...but they seem to get better with each subsequent one!!! (the counter is my favorite too!)  Thanks a ton!!!!

Comment: Regarding your question about both calls returning at the same time, my understanding is that JavaScript only has the one thread and so it won't actually process both returns simultaneously. (You can see that if you experiment with multiple timeouts.)

Comment: @toddv: Good question, I should have addressed that in the answer originally (and now have). @nnnnnn is right: JavaScript on web browsers is single-threaded, there's no possibility of the two callbacks running at the same time.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21395943/two-async-javascript-functions-with-parameters

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. Sorry I should have kindly asked you to check my new question that is totally related to this one. But I got it solved anyway.

Comment: @yazanpro: Ah, I see. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I vote for the counter method in T.J. Crowder's answer.

But, another option that hasn't been suggested is instead of doing two calls at once and then trying to sync that up with the third, do the calls one at a time. That is, make the first async call and in its callback make the second async call and then in its callback make the third call. (T.J.'s counter method is much more scalable.)

Regarding the problem you mentioned where the timeout didn't pass the data for you, that's because you're trying to pass too many arguments to `setTimeout`. You need to do it something like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ this.thirdMethod(returnedData); },
           100);
```

Comment: I'll have to play with it... I started out trying that method and it would lose the returnedData either way --- I read somewhere that I could pass in the parameter like I did above in the setTimeout method... but at this point, I'm not sure of anything.