# Two Async Javascript Functions with Parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

My question totally depends on a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6392055/javascript-testing-two-asynch-calls-before-going-to-third-function):

Regarding approach number 3 (the "counter" one): If `handleCompletion` needs a **value** from `startOtherAsync` in order to do its job. How can we implement that?

Note that that value coming from `startOtherAsync` (probably a parameter) will make `startAsync` sad and unable to call `handleCompletion` anymore.

Comment: sounds to me like you'd want to use promises via [jQuery's Deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/).

Comment: Maybe that's right. I'm looking into it, I haven't used it before.

Comment: Also, can you explain what value needs to be passed from `startOtherAsync`?

Comment: @Jack: Technically `startOtherAsync` will pass nothing. but the `success` of his ajax call will call back `handleCompletion` passing the returned ajax value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a perfect place to use promises. All the jQuery Ajax calls return promises by default which means you can simply chain them together:

```
$.ajax({/*snip*/}).then(
   function(result){

      doSomethingWithResult(result);

      return $.ajax({/*snip*/});

   }).then(function(result){

      doSomeFinalProcessing(result);

   });
```

And of course, a [jsFiddle to demonstrate this happening](http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/gw2SC/).

Here is an updated fiddle that shows how to combine multiple simultaneous promises and combine their results.

http://jsfiddle.net/jwcarroll/U3N9u/

And the code:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}

function doStuffLater(msg){
    var def = $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function(){

        def.resolve(msg);

    }, getRandomInt(300, 1000));

    return def.promise();
}

function needsBothReturns(one, two){
    console.log({one:one, two:two});
}

var first = doStuffLater("Sent First");
var second = doStuffLater("Sent Second");

$.when(first, second).done(function(result1, result2){
    needsBothReturns(result1, result2);
});
```

Comment: It looks like this implements a callback chain not separate async functions with a third waiting function.

Comment: @yazanpro - If you look at the fiddle, each call to doSomething later is indeed asynchronous. You can also create your own deferred if you need to execute to things simultaneously.

Comment: Yeah, That's pretty clear now. It addresses my problem and I realized the concept as well. Thank you for your update.